# What component is required for this fly in options list?

Tags: reactjs, list, react-native, select, optionmenu

Is there a built in React Native component to make this fly in options list (screenshot below)? If not, is there a third party component?

The example below is the Wikipedia app Saved Pages list. When 'Sort' is tapped, this menu shows. I want to do the same in my React Native app. I know how to sort the list I just don't know what this component would be called or if there is one.

Notable features of the Wikipedia example:

- It flys in from the bottom
- The background is dimmed like a modal
- It's for a limited list of options (unlike a select that can have many)

I've checked and it doesn't look like there is a built in component, and the third party ones are like a select where the options show in place on the view, instead of like a modal.

[image: Options menu]